# Why does this transformation matrix behave diffrent than expected?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt(2)}{2}& \sqrt(2)+1\\
\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}& \frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}& \sqrt(2)-1\\
0& 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I have this transformation matrix for homogenous coordinates. From what I understand, the top-left 4 entries stand for rotation, which in this case is 45 degrees counterclockwise, and the last column is a translation by ($\sqrt(2)+1, \sqrt(2)-1$).

According to the answer, the rotation is indeed 45 degrees but the translation is by $(2, −√2)$ and I have absolutely no idea why.

What causes the general rule to not work here?

Comment: It's sort of hard to say why the rule breaks without knowing the rule you have in mind, but note that $\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\ \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2} / 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \sqrt{2} + 1 \\ 0 & 1 & \sqrt{2} - 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is not equal to the matrix in the question---work it out. The elements in positions $(1, 3)$ and $(2, 3)$ are affected by the rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to identify the transformation as a rotation and a translation, but it is not quite that easy to decode what the translation is, *depending on the order of operations*.

If we translate first, then rotate, since the translation by $a$ units in the $x$-direction and $b$ units in the $y$-direction,
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, $$
has (potentially) nonzero elements (namely $a$ and $b$) in the last column, the entries in the "translation positions" of the product
$$\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\ \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2} / 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
will not just be $a$ and $b$.

In particular, note that we have
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\ \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2} / 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2} + 1 \\ \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2} / 2 & \sqrt{2} - 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}. $$
So computing the $(1, 3)$ and $(2, 3)$ entries of the product we must have
$$ \begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} a - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} b = \sqrt{2} + 1 \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} a + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} b = \sqrt{2} - 1. \end{cases}$$

Adding the two equations we get $\sqrt{2} a = 2 \sqrt{2}$, so $a = 2$, and hence (e.g.) $\sqrt{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} b = \sqrt{2} - 1$, so $b = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = -\sqrt{2}$.

On the other hand, if we rotate first and then translate, we have
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\ \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2} / 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & a \\ \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2} / 2 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, $$
and so in this order we can read off the translation directly.

Comment: I see! Indeed, there was no general rule, I just conjured it myself... Thank you for the detailed explanation!